# Getting Image index

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing an app in that i have 15 images for stored in an array as front images and another 15 images as back image. I want to add that image to scrollview vertically i have done that successfully but now my problem is that how can I compare that two array images.

Adding front images on vertical scrollview added succesfully but not randomly shuffled, ie when I double tap on the front image the back array image is displayed but still front image present in that imageview.

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**Please check my code :**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    delegate.front=TRUE;
    delegate.back=FALSE;


    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

    FrontsCards=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cloub1.png",@"cloub2.png",@"cloub3.png",@"cloub4.png",@"cloub5.png",@"cloub6.png",@"cloub7.png",@"cloub8.png",@"cloub9.png",@"cloub10.png",@"cloub11.png",@"cloub12.png",@"diamond1.png",@"diamond2.png",@"diamond3.png",@"diamond4.png",@"diamond5.png", nil];

    for(int m=0; m<[FrontsCards count];m++)
      {
        ImgView.tag=m;

        int randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];


        NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];

    //  NSLog(@"%d",randIdx);


        NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];

        int padding=25;
        // padding is given.

        CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*m+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);

        ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

        [ImgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];


        [scrollView addSubview:ImgView];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapImgView:)];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        doubleTap.delegate = self;

        [self.ImgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

        self.ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


    }

    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*[FrontsCards count], scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];




}


- (void)doubleTapImgView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{


    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    delegate.back=TRUE;

    delegate.front=FALSE;


    NSLog(@"%d", gesture.view.tag);

        NSLog(@"double-tap");

    BackCards =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"card1.jpg",@"card2.jpg",@"card3.jpg",@"card4.jpg", nil];

    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

    for(int m=0; m< [BackCards count];m++)
    {       
        NSString *imageName=[BackCards objectAtIndex:m];

        NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];

        int padding=25;
        // padding is given.

        CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*m+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);

        ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

        [ImgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];


        [scrollView addSubview:ImgView];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapImgView:)];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        doubleTap.delegate = self;

        [self.ImgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

        self.ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


    }

    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*[FrontsCards count], scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

}
```

Comment: are you using gestures for changing the image?

Comment: i used scroolview to change the iamge vertically.

Comment: when you double tap on image which method will call?for that what you are using gestures?

Comment: You could also use tableview for this. Is your requirement is different from tableView?

Comment: you want to change all the images or particuler image?

Comment: your code sounds like every time new scollview created and added it the view.

Comment: yes i want to change all image.

Comment: how may i create a single scrollview and add that images into that scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving this one you can set `Tag` value for every image when you tap on that particuler image you'l get tag value and use that `tag` value.

```
self.imagview.tag=Unique_tagValue;
```

when click on that image you can set image   from another Array.

```
self.imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[backArray objectAtIndex:self.imageview.tag]];
```

EDIT:-

in `viewDidLoad` method set tags for imageview like this, `ImgView.tag=m+100;`

keep below code in `doubleTapImgView` method

```
 for(int m=0; m< [BackCards count];m++)
    { 
      UIImageView *imgview=(UIImageView *)[scrollview viewWithTag:m+100];
      imgview.image=[UIImage imagNamed:[BackCards objectAtIndex:m]];
    }
```

Subview Translation:-

```
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:frontview];
```

Comment: when i double tapped on front array image the image upadate to imageview change it to the back array but still the front image stay backside i want to remove that image wn=hen back image displayed.

Comment: @Jitendra Deore:means you are adding another imageview to scroll when double click on that image.simply change the image for that particular imageview.

Comment: no no it's a single imageview i just change the image when user tapped.

Comment: @Jitendra Deore:ypu want to change all the images or tapped imageview image only?

Comment: i wanted to display same back array image multiple time when user dobble tapped on front image.

Comment: this solve my issue now i want something like that when i tapped the image that image still presnt backside and new back images array loaded and when i doubble tapped on that back array images the old one front array tapped image displayed on back array doubl etapped.

Comment: for that crete two different views with images and change the views.

Comment: if you want to support me please help me to increase my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use the same name for the images in backArray and front Array or you can set the tag value of each image uniquely and compares that tags to solve the problem.

```
 imgV.tag=tagValue;
```

Hope this helps.